# frontend user with custom profile pages

Tags: front-end, profiles, user-registration

i am building a website where the frontend users can register and they need to have custom profile pages - not the standard WordPress backend pages that the admin sees.

There they can see their profile (image, name, email, ...) and change it, as well as some site specific pages like: statistics, severals lists, ... .

is there a plugin for this?
or if not could you please point me to some documentation or other links that might help?

Thanks.

Comment: both answers are very much valid. since i cannot choose both i went with BuddyPress as that was in this project my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using BuddyPress? BuddyPress allows all these thing, and has many other features ( though things can be turned on and off if it's too much )

Comment: i will take a look. i have not used it yet. is it possible to have a fully customized user profile?

Comment: Yes, its a fully templatable system, complete with activity streams groups forums etc (can be turned off)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [Profile Builder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/profile-builder/screenshots/) plugin which allows front-end login, registration and edit profile by using shortcodes.

Comment: does this plugin allow the customization of their profile pages?

Comment: yep, but it has more features on the paid version